# Invalid parameter for sklearn estimator Ridge() and Lasso()

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, lasso-regression, gridsearchcv

I am implementing an example from a tutorial, using P**ython 3.6.5** and **scikit-learn 0.23.2**

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV 
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge

ridge = Ridge()

r_parameters = {'ridge__alpha:':[1e-15, 1e-10, 1e-8, 1e-4, 1e-3, 1e-2, 1, 5, 10, 20]}

ridge_regressor = GridSearchCV(ridge, r_parameters, scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error', cv = 5)

ridge_regressor.fit(X, y)
```

The error being returned boils down to:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter ridge for estimator Ridge(). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

The same problem when I am doing it for Lasso

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso

lasso = Lasso(tol=0.05)
l_parameters = {'lasso__alpha:':[1e-15, 1e-10, 1e-8, 1e-4, 1e-3, 1e-2, 1, 5, 10, 20]}

lasso_regressor = GridSearchCV(lasso, l_parameters, scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error', cv = 5)

lasso_regressor.fit(X, y)
```

Similar error for lasso as seen below:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter lasso for estimator Lasso(tol=0.05). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: At what line is the error happening ?

Comment: @JosephBudin

Error is happening at:
ridge_regressor.fit(X, y) and
lasso_regressor.fit(X, y) respectively

Comment: Try `l_parameters = {'alpha:':[1e-15, ... `

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @SergeyBushmanov, you should use `alpha` as parameter, see [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html) for `Ridge()` and [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html) for `Lasso()`.

Moreover, note that you wrote the colon inside the quote. That is a typo.

To sum up:

`r_parameters = {'alpha':[1e-15, 1e-10, 1e-8, 1e-4, 1e-3, 1e-2, 1, 5, 10, 20]}`

and

`l_parameters = {'alpha':[1e-15, 1e-10, 1e-8, 1e-4, 1e-3, 1e-2, 1, 5, 10, 20]}`